# Email custom column field person

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, workflow-lookup

I created a custom field in my documents folder, which is a person. I have names this new column authors. I want to create a workflow that emails the person I have imported into this field. When I do the lookup function for a email workflow it won't allow me to exit out of the look up with Documents > Author> return as string.

How is my look up suppose to look?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should select "Current Item" in "Data source" section in above screen shot. 
field from source is "Authors", return field as "Email Address". 
see the below image in your case "Modified By" as "Authors"

[image]